# Is it possible to pass a widget as a parameter to a function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, widget, parameter-passing

There are several switches in the app's layout, and when these switches are pressed, the value of sharedPreference is changed to determine whether a specific function is performed. For example, if the funcOnOff switch is off, the voice notification function is off, and when fromOnOff is off, caller information cannot be checked when a notification is received.

I am using several source codes that work almost similarly as below. Is it possible to pass multiple android.widgets as parameters to a function so that these actions can be acted upon as a single function?

```
var funcOnOff: Switch = findViewById(R.id.func_on_off)
var fromOnOff: Switch = findViewById(R.id.from_on_off)
var timeOnOff: Switch = findViewById(R.id.time_on_off)
var contentOnOff: Switch = findViewById(R.id.content_on_off)

funcOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            editor.putString("func", "ON")
        } else {
            editor.putString("func", "OFF")
        }
        editor.commit()
    }
    fromOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            editor.putString("from", "ON")
        } else {
            editor.putString("from", "OFF")
        }
        editor.commit()
    }
    timeOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            editor.putString("time", "ON")
        } else {
            editor.putString("time", "OFF")
        }
        editor.commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can make a factory method for the `OnCheckedChangeListener`s.

```
fun onCheckedChangedListenerForPreferenceKey(key: String): CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener = { _, isChecked ->
    if (isChecked) {
        editor.putString(key, "ON") // wouldn't using putBoolean be better?
    } else {
        editor.putString(key, "OFF")
    }
    editor.commit()
}
```

Then you can do:

```
funcOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangedListenerForPreferenceKey("func"))
fromOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangedListenerForPreferenceKey("from"))
timeOnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangedListenerForPreferenceKey("time"))
```

Or you can make a list of pairs of switches to preference keys, and iterate through them:

```
listOf(
    funcOnOff to "func"
    fromOnOff to "from"
    timeOnOff to "time"
).forEach { (switch, key) -> 
    switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangedListenerForPreferenceKey(key))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general alternative to [*Sweeper*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74570464/13598222) - most widget listeners (and a lot of other UI callbacks in Android) pass in the object that generated the event as a parameter. So you can create a function that checks that parameter, and acts accordingly:

```
// If the signature here matches the listener function, you can pass a reference
// to this function directly
fun handleSwitch(switch: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
    when(switch) {
        funcOnOff -> "func"
        fromOnOff -> "from"
        timeOnOff -> "time"
        else -> null
    }?.let { key ->
         editor.putString(key, if (isChecked) "ON" else "OFF").commit()
    }
}
```

Then you can just apply that to all your switches:

```
val switches = listOf(funcOnOff, fromOnOff, timeOnOff)
switches.forEach { it.setonOnCheckedChangedListener(::handleSwitch) }

// or if you don't want to use a function reference
switches.forEach {
    it.setOnCheckedChangedListener { switch, enabled -> handleSwitch(switch, enabled) }
}

// or since you're iterating over the switches anyway, you could make the current one
// part of the callback lambda and ignore the parameters
switches.forEach { switch ->
    it.setOnCheckedChangedListener { _, _ -> handleSwitch(switch, switch.isChecked) }
}
```

You get the idea! Personally I feel like passing a function reference is neater, instead of creating a separate lambda for each switch, but honestly it depends - no need to overcomplicate things if a neat one-liner setup will get the job done!

Also personally I'd probably use a Map instead of the `when`, like in *Sweeper*'s answer - that way you can define the switches in use and their keys in one place, and then you can assign your listeners by iterating over the map's `keys`. No repeating yourself by listing the keys in one place, and then again in the `when`, y'know? Easier to maintain too, you might forget to update one of those places - but this is just a general example!